# Get MIN aggregate field from table for the past X days from updated_at timestamp column

Tags: sql, mariadb

Given the following table structure and sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `records` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `external_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sub_id` int unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  `amount` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `records` (`external_id`, `sub_id`,`amount`, `updated_at`) VALUES 
(1,    0, 160, '2022-01-13 16:00:00'),
(1, 1001, 150, '2022-01-13 16:40:00'),
(1, 1002, 170, '2022-06-13 16:40:00'),
(1, 1003, 170, '2022-06-13 16:40:00');
```

I'm trying to get the `MIN` value for `amount` for the past **X** (assume 30 days), for a given `external_id`, using the timestamp field `updated_at`, with the following constraints:

- If there are no records for the past 30 days (changes), the latest record is still a valid one,
- Each new record for a given `external_id` would "cancel and replace" the previous record,
- If there are both records with `sub_id = 0` and `sub_id <> 0`, for the same given `external_id` the records with `sub_id <> 0` would prevail.

So, the query for the above data should return `150`.

A fiddle and what I have tried at: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=e4ddd6b55dbccf607633c1cf7d9cd4ef

Extra Information (Later edit)

To give you a better picture of the whole idea here:
Each time an update is made on the `amount` field, there is a new record created in the `records` table (to create a history log).

My task is to query the `MIN` amount for the past 30 days.
Some `external_id` records also have that `sub_id`.
Whether there is or isn't a `sub_id`, the record for the `external_id` would be created.
Amounts with `sub_id` are usually bigger (something extra gets added to the amount for `product_id`).

Comment: That fiddle includes data, but nothing that you've tried.  To clarify; are you using MySQL 5.6? (very out of date, I recommend upgrading to MySQL 8)  What do you mean by "cancel and replace"?  Please could you update your example to demonstrate the behaviour if there are multiple `external_id` values?

Comment: I am actually using `MariaDB 10.6.8` which should be compatible with the latest versions of MySQL for the most part.

Comment: Please edit your tags to actually state MariaDB (rather than MySQL), and possibly use [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=6345c8c2351589d7ce28742c0e3d754b) so you can choose MariaDB.

Comment: Can you explain why your expected result is 150? There are 2 rows for 2022-06-13 (last 30 days) with sub_id <> 0 and amount = 170.

Comment: Because the records which were created on `2022-06-13` (today) have the amount value greater than the amount value created on `2022-01-13` and was valid between `2022-01-13 -> 2022-06-12` (and that interval intersects with the past 30 days)

Comment: I believe I managed to create a minimal reproducible example. Please take a look at the first two inserted rows: the first one has `sub_id = 0` and the second one `sub_id <> 0` however the second one should prevail.

Comment: It's still unclear what to do if the data has multiple `external_id` values.  It's still unclear why a value from 5 months ago takes precedence over a value from today *(considering you state you only want values from the last 30 days)*.

Comment: This is the database design. You can consider that `updated_at` is used as a `start_at` for the given row and the `end_at` for the previously created record for the same `external_id`.

Comment: Values are not created every day, that way I would query for the records created after a given date.

But because records are only created when a change is made on the `amount` value, and they would be valid until a new record is made, I need to take into amount all values which would be valid in the given interval (between 30 days ago and now)

Comment: Maybe if you would read `updated_at` as `valid_from` it would be easier to understand how the database structure was designed.  If a record was created a year ago, and another one today, the first one would be valid between "30 days ago" and yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it's not clear what should happen if there are multiple `external_id` values.  You seem to want only one row returned?  *(If this is not the case, please improve the example to include the desired results when there are multiple different `external_id` values.)*

If you do just want one value returned, you could simply `ORDER BY <something> LIMIT 1`

I, however, am going to ***assume*** you want just one value ***per `external_id`***.

```
WITH
  filtered_sorted
AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY external_id
                           ORDER BY CASE WHEN sub_id <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
                                    amount
                      )
                        AS rn
  FROM
    records  AS r
  WHERE
    updated_at >= (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(updated_at), DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                     FROM records
                    WHERE updated_at  <= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
                      AND external_id  = r.external_id
                  )
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  filtered_sorted
WHERE
  rn = 1
```

This is based on the notion that the most recent row ***on or before*** the start of the day 30 days ago is still valid and should be included in consideration for the lowest amount.

- For each `external_id`...

  - Ignore all records `updated_at` ***after*** the start of 30 days ago
  - Return the most recent remaining `updated_at` *(which could be exactly the start of the day 30 days ago)*
  - If no such row is found, return the start of the day 30 days ago
  - We will consider all rows for that `updated_at` onwards

Then the `ROW_NUMBER()` prefers rows with a non-zero `sub_id` and then rows with the lowest `amount`.

- For the rows being considered, after the `WHERE` clause described above

  - Assign each row a row number
  - Each `external_id` should have it's own individual sequence of row numbers *(achieved with `PARTITION BY` external_id`)*
  - Rows with `sub_id <> 0` should come before before any rows with `sub_id = 0` *(achieved by `ORDER BY CASE WHEN sub_id <> 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`)*
  - Rows with lower `amount` values should come first *(achieved with `ORDER BY amount.)*

Then, just return rows where the assigned row number is 1

- Partitioned by `external_id`
- Filtered by `updated_at`
- Sorted by `sub_id <> 0`, `amount`

*(One row per `external_id`)*

[Demo on dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=86d33d8c49e385f1581aa2fe14f25de2)

Comment: This seems to return what I need. Could you please break it down and explain a bit? Especially this part: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY external_id`

Comment: And your assumption was correct, I need to get that amount for a given `external_id`, even if the `records` table contains thousands of records for other `external_id` values.